# MySQL JSON array in Where in condition

Tags: mysql, sql, json

It's working but returning just one Record. I Have 5 in Total.

**Catalog.similar** is json type field. I remove [""] from the return and putting inside the WHERE IN Condition. But I get just one record.

```
SELECT * FROM similar_codes a WHERE a.id IN (SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR(c.similar,2,LENGTH(c.similar)-2),'"','') FROM catalog c WHERE c.id=1)
```

The Return from the select inside the WHERE IN is.

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR(c.similar,2,LENGTH(c.similar)-2),'"','') FROM catalog c WHERE c.id=1)

3380, 3382, 1952, 3384, 3383
```

Comment: remove where codition with id

Comment: it's always bad idea to save list in filed. You need to create `similar` table which will be linked to catalog. Then just use simple join.

Comment: i trying to use json field... it's a bad idea json at all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to develop your own way to search JSON, why not use the built in functions? Alternatively, if you are using a version of MySQL that doesn't support JSON data, you might be better looking at using a linked table.

```
-- Create main table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test (id INT(11));
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (3380), (3382), (1952), (3384), (3383);

-- Create JSON table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_search (id INT(11), similar JSON);
INSERT INTO test_search (id, similar) VALUES (1, JSON_ARRAY(3380, 3382, 1952, 3384, 3383));

-- Select
SELECT t.id 
FROM (SELECT similar AS ids FROM test_search WHERE id = 1) ts
INNER JOIN test t ON JSON_CONTAINS(ts.ids, CAST(t.id AS json), '$');
```

Comment: Thank's. It's Worked

Comment: Precise answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT()

```
SELECT * FROM similar_codes a WHERE a.id IN 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(SUBSTR(c.similar,2,LENGTH(c.similar)-2),'"','')) FROM catalog c WHERE c.id=1)
```

Comment: keep returning one record. the first 3380

Comment: And what does this query return? SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(REPLACE(SUBSTR(c.similar,2,LENGTH(c.similar)-2),'"','')) FROM catalog c WHERE c.id=1;

Comment: Get all similars. ["3380", "3382", "1952", "3384", "3383"]